# How to make Terraform IGNORE a resource if another one is not deployed

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

I am using Terraform (and Terragrunt) to deploy Kubernetes manifests. I am dealing with the following situation: I am describing a Helm Chart for `cert-manager` and a Kubernetes manifest for a `cert-manager.io/v1/ClusterIssues`.

Here's the definition of the Helm Chart:

```
resource "helm_release" "cert_manager" {
  name       = "cert-manager"
  namespace  = kubernetes_namespace.cert_manager.metadata.0.name
  chart      = "cert-manager"
  repository = "https://charts.jetstack.io"
  wait       = true

  # ...

  set {
    name  = "installCRDs"
    value = "true"
  }
}
```

Here's the `ClusterIssuer`:

```
resource "kubernetes_manifest" "clusterissuer_letsencrypt" {
  manifest = {
    apiVersion = "cert-manager.io/v1"
    kind       = "ClusterIssuer"
    metadata = {
      name = "letsencrypt"
    }

    # ...
  }

  depends_on = [helm_release.cert_manager]
}
```

When creating a brand new Kubernetes cluster, the CRDs for the `ClusterIssuer` don't exist, and Terraform fails to `plan` the execution because:

```
│ Error: Failed to determine GroupVersionResource for manifest
|   ...
│   24: resource "kubernetes_manifest" "clusterissuer_letsencrypt" {
│
│ no matches for kind "ClusterIssuer" in group "cert-manager.io"
```

Now, I understand how `depends_on` works and I understand that I can do a targeted deployment with Terraform and I can solve this in sort of a two-phased deployment, but I want to avoid manual actions as much as possible.

Are there any mechanisms in Terraform (or Terragrunt, just in case) that can make it ignore the presence of this `ClusterIssuer` manifest altogether if the Helm Chart for `cert-manager` is not deployed?

Comment: Terrgrunt could solve this one quite nicely of you split these resources out and use terragrunts run-all which will apply them as two separate groups in the order but will under the hood run them as two separate terraform applys

Comment: @ChrisDoyle fair enough - I was thinking that could be our way out, but I was hoping it won't get to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way for both of these to be completed in a single plan-apply cycle, because `kubernetes_manifest` relies on schema information from the cluster in order to produce its plan.

Instead, you will need to choose *some* strategy for splitting this across two runs. Here are some examples:

- You can bootstrap by using `-target` to ask Terraform to focus only on creating the cluster first. This is a common choice because it requires special actions only during the initial creation step, but you did already exclude this option in your question.
- You can split your configuration into at least two parts. The first part would declare only the cluster itself. The second part might refer to the cluster using a `data` block (declaring that it ought to already exist) and then do all of the cluster configuration using the `hashicorp/kubernetes` provider.

  This can be a good option if you expect that you'll rarely make changes to the cluster itself, and that your everyday work will be in changing manifests within the cluster. If you are frequently changing the cluster at the same time as its contents then this will be inconvenient, since you'll always need to run Terraform once for each configuration.

There are other variations of these two strategies with some different details but the above are the two main classes of solution here: either you have one configuration and ask Terraform to only plan and apply a part of it during initial creation, or you have two configurations so that you can use a normal Terraform workflow for both of them but it'll be more complicated to make changes to them both together.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. I am not regularly changing the cluster, but the resources around it, yes, e.g. managed databases. I suppose, in summary, I am frequently making changes to resources that rely on more than just the Kubernetes provider, but I presume this would be easily doable with Terragrunt.

Comment: The only _crucial_ thing is that you be able to plan the cluster separately from anything using `kubernetes_manifest`. From Terraform's perspective there's no problem with planning other infrastructure such as databases at the same time as `kubernetes_manifest`, because there is presumably no dependency between the schema in the Kubernetes cluster and the managed databases. You could put the database declarations in the same configuration as the `kubernetes_manifest` resources if it's likely that you'll be changing both of them together.